# Dynamically changing CSS property when conditional statement is met using JSTL

Tags: html, css, jstl

I am aiming to dynamically change CSS properties of a HTML button inside an if statement, when the condition is met. I have a brief idea on how it would work but not sure on how you would change the current css property in JSTL.

For example

```
<input type="submit" value="Previous" class="button"/> 
 <c:if test = "condition goes here">
      //change or set css properties here
 </c:if>
```

Comment: How will that be done ?

Comment: I already know what the ${...} represents. Its just dynamically changing css properties inside that condition. Or is there a similar example for me to follow.

Comment: An example is when that condition is met, I want to change the color of the css property

Comment: How would i write this inside the if statement ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline style if you want or make a better implementation creating a new style tag in this way:

**Solution 1**

```
<input type="submit" value="Previous" class="button" <c:if test = "condition goes here">style="css-style:${yourProp}"</c:if>/>
```

**Solution 2**

```
<c:if test = "condition goes here">
  <style type='text/css'>
     .button{css-style:${yourProp}}
  </style>
</c:if>
<input type="submit" value="Previous" class="button"/>
```

with the second solution the big problem is that all the elements next to the style will take the style, so you need some id or identifier.

Comment: I have used solution 1 and it works fine. Appreciate the help